# How to program rules for card game

Tags: game-design, logic, card-game

Hi I want to program a card game,
in my game each card can do multiple actions, depend on the situation in which the player is facing.
For example There is an "Attack" card which can attack another player, the attacked player can defend itself in multiple ways - it can use "Run Away" card, it also may use another card to rule a cube to avoid the attack etc,
The "Attack" may also be used to shot an attacker to avoid dying.
In short each card can be used in all sort of ways and I'm having trouble to code these rules,
How can I create the session between 2 players? (attacker and defender) 
thanks

Comment: This is pretty a pretty broad question. Try breaking it up into smaller components, so we can answer more specific questions rather than try to tackle the whole system at once.

Comment: We have [several](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/104553/39518) [existing](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/103558/39518) [questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/122249/39518) in the [tag:card-game] tag that touch on high-level strategies for authoring highly flexible behaviours for trading card game content. Have you reviewed these for some starting points? What have you tried based on your research so far, and where are you stuck in need of additional help?